# htaccess folder rewrite and show index from folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite my url: http://domain.com/administration to domain.com/admin

But the index.html of that subdirectory is not available when i use http://domain.com/admin/

How can I fix that?

This is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) administration/$1.php
```

Comment: That is because your rules will rewrite `/admin/` to `/administration/.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these. You probably need the external for admin to work as you expect.

```
# fix missing trailing / on admin
RewriteRule ^admin$ /admin/ [NS,L,R=301]
# change admin dir
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) administration/$1 [NS,DPI]
# load anything that's not a directory as php
RewriteRule ^(?>[^.]+)(?<!/)$ $0.php [NS,L]
```